# Accessing ports remotely

Tags: apache-http-server, port, port-forwarding, iptables, jira

I have a fedora server on a local network which I can access through VNC.

I am trying to install a JIRA plugin called Activity timeline, these are both built using Java.

When I log into VNC and view:

```
http://localhost:8040/setup/index
```

I can see the correct page.

However when I attempt to access this page remotely:

```
http://ourip:8040/setup/index
```

The page times out. I have JIRA running on port 8094 which I can access:

```
http://ourip:8094/
```

I am not sure what I need to do to make this port available.

I can see that 8040 may already be running something else, I don't want this running on this port any more.

```
$grep -w 8040 /etc/services 
ampify          8040/tcp                # Ampify Messaging Protocol
ampify          8040/udp                # Ampify Messaging Protocol

$ netstat -tulpn | grep -w 8040
tcp        0      0 :::8040                     :::*                        LISTEN      11425/java
```

My iptables file looks like this:

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5900 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 5900 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5902 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 5902 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8094 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8040 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Where I added this line:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8040 -j ACCEPT
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your newly added

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8040 -j ACCEPT
```

only comes **after** the general reject rule

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Move it before that and it should work.